# Integrating Mailchimp embeded form with an SSL website

Tags: ssl, mailchimp

I am trying to integrate a Mailchimp sign up form with my website. I generated the form in Mailchimp and copied the embed code to my site. The problem is that my site has an SSL certificate and when my potential clients try to sign up to my mailing list it gives them a security warning (in firefox) saying:

"Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by a third party.

Are you sure you want to continue sending this information"

Is there any way to avoid getting this warning?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer. No

Longer answer. No, you are stuck with that warning. You are posting to an unsecured site from a secured site and the user will get this notification.

Comment: This is incorrect. Mailchimp now works over HTTPS. See @ronak's answer but basically, replace "http://" at the beginning of the url in the <form>'s action with just "//". That will maintain the form submission within the current protocol and works whether your website is running on HTTP or HTTPS.

Comment: @Digs If you just replace the http:// with // then you will geht errors if you do not change the URL also like Ronak pointed out.

Answer (score 20):

I was also facing the same problem using default embed code provided by mailchimp, but that wasn't working on SSL site.

So after Googling for solution i found this link:

Stop MailChimp Forms Breaking Your SSL

https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/mailchimp-forms-ssl/

and it wasn't a big problem simply need to change the url from list-manage1.com to "list-manage.com"

simply need to test after removing 1 from the list-manage1.com and it worked fine after that.

It also works fine for post-json embed urls.

Comment: Works for me still in March 2017

Comment: The change to "list-manage.com" alone was not enough. I had to use "https://" instead of "//" to get it working finally.

Comment: This works for me. My question is why I guess? Why doesn't mailchimp use this to begin with?

Answer (score 3):

It's more work than a simple embed, but you can do this using the MailChimp API which has support for SSL. See the section entitled [HTTPS / Secure Connections](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/#https-secure-connections) in the API docs.

Answer (score -2):

You can edit the form Mailchimp provide to embed so that it uses https and not http in the action url.

Comment: Have you actually tried this? I have, and it doesn't work. I get "Access Denied - You don't have permission to access [foo]" when you try and hit that page over https.

Comment: I did do it. I wonder if access is browser specific or it was related to how I created the form?